# Cannot add an icon to Resources

Tags: cocoa, xcode

Have been inputting and testing some sample code and everything seems to be ok.  Just that suddenly I am running into this very frustrating problem of trying to add an icon to the project.  Have downloaded an icon file (extension : icns) to my desktop and dragged it to the "Resources" group in xCode.  Then a dialogue comes up from xCode where I checked the 2 options : "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" and "Recursively create groups for any added folders".  But when I press the "Add" button, an "Alert" message box would come up.  It says "Could not copy the icon to ...".  Hope that someone knowledgable in this area would give me some hints...

Comment: Can you add other kinds of resources? Like .png files? Maybe there is something wrong with the file you downloaded.

Comment: I think I did manage to add the file into the "Resources" group once.  But the sample program, despite working perfectly otherwise, was not using the new icon at all.  So I deleted it from the "Resources" group. And now I cannot add it back again ...

Comment: OK, when you "delete" something from Xcode, it usually gives you 2 choices: `Delete References` and `Also Move to Trash`. You happened to choose `Delete References`, which just removes the references to those files from the Xcode project, but leaves the items within your project folder. That's why attempting to add the item again failed (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This failure message usually results from attempting to add a file (that is outside the project folder), when a file with that name already exists in the target location within the project folder.

For example, let's say your project folder is `~/Developer/CoolProject/`, and the Xcode project is at `~/Developer/CoolProject/CoolProject.xcodeproj`. If you drag an image, `coolImage.png`, from your Desktop to Xcode with the options set as you described, Xcode will copy the image file to `~/Developer/CoolProject/coolImage.png`. If you then repeat this same procedure, it will fail the second time with that error message.

What I would do is, in the Finder, check inside your project folder to see if the icns file has already been copied into the project folder. If there's a copy of the icns file already in the project folder, and that icns file isn't listed in the Groups & Files list in Xcode, you can resolve the problem by dragging the existing copy (that's inside the project folder) into the Xcode project window to bring up the Add File dialog. You can keep the same options as before, and this time, Xcode won't need to copy the image and so you'll avoid the error.

[UPDATED] OK, so what you'll want to do, based on the comment above, is go in the Finder and remove the existing .icns file from your project (in other words, move it to the Trash). Then you can re-add an icon with the same name (from a location outside your project folder) without getting the error. Also, in the future, remember that you might want to consider using the `Also Move to Trash` option when deleting files from within Xcode, if you no longer want the unused items inside your project folder.

Also, you may want to double-check to make sure the file in question is included as part of the Active Target. For example, if you add a file to your project, but the "include in active target" checkbox for the file is unchecked (like the `ReadMe.rtfd` file in the image below), then the file won't be copied into your application bundle at build time or be available at runtime.

[image]

(To add that Active Target checkbox column to the Groups & Files list, Control-click on the table column header view and choose Target Membership from the menu).

Comment: And if you want the icon to show up for the app or for a particular file type make sure you set the file to be the icon for the appropriate item in Xcode. There is a place in the document types list to tell Xcode which icon goes to which file type and a place to indicate the app icon as well (I would set this _after_ you add the icon file).

Comment: you are right, the icon file is still in the project folder without showing itself under the Resources group.  I've done what you suggested, drag the existing file to the Resources group and the Add File dialog is brought up. And this time I have no problem in pushing the "Add" button.  But the problem is, the sample program is still not using the new icon.  Any extra hints ?

Comment: Assuming you want the newly added icon file to be the application icon go to the properties section of your target (in 3.x select Targets under the Groups & Files list then select the target and get info, then look in the properties tab; in 4.x select root level of project and look in the Summary tab) enter the file name into the icon file spot (or drag the file there). Also as NSGod says make sure the file is being included in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

Comment: Got it + thank you all.  Without your comments and answers the problem can definitely not be solved easily ...